# emberJS does not display model data

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using emberJS to display data obtained from REST API. My ember app connects to REST server and server returns the JSON data, but when I try to display id of my restaurant in the template I get this output:

```
Restaurant id is:
```

Here are my models:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

//restaurant.js model
export default DS.Model.extend({
    restaurantId: DS.attr('int'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    rating: DS.attr('double'),
    phone: DS.attr('double'),
    reservationPrice: DS.attr('double'),
    workingHours: DS.attr('string'),
    deals: DS.attr('string'),
    image: DS.attr('string'),

    //Relations
    coordinates: DS.belongsTo('coordinates'),
    address: DS.belongsTo('address')
});

//coordinates.js model
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    latitude: DS.attr("double"),
    longitude: DS.attr("double"),

    //Relations
    restaurant: DS.belongsTo('restaurant')
});

//address.js model
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    streetName: DS.attr("string"),
    city: DS.attr("string"),
    country: DS.attr("string"),

    //Relations
    restaurant: DS.belongsTo('restaurant')
});
```

my template:

```
Restaurant id is: <br>
{{restaurant.restaurantId}}
<br>
{{model.restaurantId}}


{{#each model as |restaurant|}}
    <h2>{{restaurant.image}}</h2>
{{/each}}
```

and my route:

```
//restaurant.js route
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.store.findAll('restaurant');
    }
});
```

and of course, my serializer:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({

    normalizeFindAllResponse(store, type, payload){
        return {
            id: "restaurantId",
            data: {
                type: type.modelName,
                id: "restaurantId",
                attributes: {
                    id: "restaurantId",
                    restaurantId: payload.restaurantId,
                    name: payload.name,
                    address: payload.address,
                    phone: payload.phone,
                    workingHours: payload.workingHours,
                    rating: payload.rating,
                    image: payload.image
                }
            }
        };
    }

});
```

Here is the JSON I get from server:

```
[ {
  "restaurantId" : 1,
  "name" : "Some name",
  "address" : {
    "streetName" : "some street",
    "city" : "some town",
    "country" : "some country"
  },
  "phone" : 984894,
  "workingHours" : "08:00 - 23:00",
  "rating" : 3.0,
  "image" : "www.somelink.com"
}, 
...
]
```

I can see in Chrome inspector that my ember App makes a request to server and server responds with JSON. And there are no errors nor warnings, but my model data just does not get displayed. Any help is appreciated.

**edit:**

I wrote this normalizeFindRecord in my serializer, and now it looks like this:

```
normalizeFindRecordResponse(store, type, payload){
        return {
            data: {
                type: type.modelName,
                id: "restaurantId",
                address: DS.belongsTo('restaurant', {embedded: true} ),
                attributes: {
                    restaurantId: payload.restaurantId,
                    name: payload.name,
                    address: payload.address,
                    phone: payload.phone,
                    workingHours: payload.workingHours,
                    rating: payload.rating,
                    image: payload.image,
                    coordinates: payload.coordinates
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

and now when I try route `this.store.findRecord('restaurant', 1);` I get

```
Restaurant id is: 
1
```

but the findAllRoute does still not work.

Comment: Which ember.js version are you using? Did you provide transforms for "int"? I think it's "number". See following link for all standard attributes: [DS.attr](http://emberjs.com/api/data/#method_attr)

Comment: I use 2.4.0 version. I didn't provide any extra transformation. I had that transformation error while I was using JSONAPISerializer and once I changed that to RESTSerializer that error is gone.

Comment: The error should not be gone, since the transform "int" does not exist. In addition, your normalizeFindAllResponse is weird. Could you try to explain, what you want to achieve with that code? If you want to redeclare the primary key of your model, then you should use the property [primaryKey](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#property_primaryKey)

Comment: Could you please check the edit in my question. I want to achieve to get my JSON into my model. If I replace id with primaryKey I get the error that id is not set.

Comment: I think `normalizeFindAllResponse` will get an array as payload and should return an array under `data`.